# Detect or pass calling method in Entity Framework 6 and Entity Framework Core via IDbCommandInterceptor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm interested in capturing the name of the method that initiated an Entity Framework query. I will be using this functionality in both Entity Framework 6 and Entity Framework Core

Consider the following class:

```
namespace MyCompany.MyApp
{
    public class MyDataClass
    {
        // ... snip ...
        
        public Person GetPerson(long id)
        {
            return _dbContext
                .Person
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

And the following interceptor:

```
public class EFCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    // ... snip other interface methods ...

    public void ReaderExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        var callingMehtod = GetCallingMethod() // <--- I'd like this to return the string "MyCompany.MyApp.MyDataClass.GetPerson"
    }
}
```

Is there any way to determine what method initiated the query that resulted in the interceptor being called?

As I'm going to be using this functionality for tracing and performance analysis, I can't send and record the entire `Environment.StackTrace` for every query running through the system.

I also considered using the `StackTrace` class in conjunction with `stackTrace.GetFrames()` to try to analyze the call stack to find the actual method that initiated the query, but it's not clear how to do this reliably without relying on some kind of namespace convention that universally identifies a data access class.

Another approach that would be acceptable might look something like:

```
namespace MyCompany.MyApp
{
    public class MyDataClass
    {
        // ... snip ...
        
        public Person GetPerson(long id)
        {
            return _dbContext
                .Person
                .WithExtraInterceptorContext(new { CallingMethod = "MyCompany.MyApp.MyDataClass.GetPerson"}) // <--- Can something like this be done?
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

The intention with the above example would be able to later retrieve the extra context via the `DbCommandInterceptionContext` inside `IDbCommandInterceptor`

Ultimately, the problem I'm trying to solve is to get the fully qualified name of the method that initiated a query without having a full call stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply register the information before running the query, something like:

```
    public Person GetPerson(long id)
    {
        EfDebug.SetCurrentMethodName();
        return _dbContext
            .Person
            .WithExtraInterceptorContext(new { CallingMethod = "MyCompany.MyApp.MyDataClass.GetPerson"}) // <--- Can something like this be done?
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
    }
```

. . .

```
   static class EfDebugExtensions
    {
        public static AsyncLocal<string> CurrentMethodName = new AsyncLocal<string>();
        public static void SetCurrentMethodName([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
        {
            CurrentMethodName.Value = caller;
        }
        public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,[CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
        {
            CurrentMethodName.Value = caller;
            var rv = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(source);
            return rv;
        }
        public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, [CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
        {
            CurrentMethodName.Value = caller;
            var rv = Enumerable.ToList(source);
            return rv;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How would this work in a scenario where requests are pouring in and async calls are happening? By the time the interceptor ran, couldn't the CurrentMethodName end up being different / wrong?

Comment: Stick the information in an `AsyncLocal<EfDebug>` then. The code shown *could* go in an extension method on `IQueryable<T>` that sets the info using `CallerMemberAttributes` and returns the original queryable. But be careful with that approach as it wouldn't work if you defer your execution (return the query to be executed elsewhere)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Interesting. Another way to do it might be to make overloads to all the query realization methods. That would get around deferred execution

Comment: I like that one.  I'm gonna steal it for an update for my answer.

Comment: I agree.  I did not know that was available for EF6.

Answer (score 2):

With EF Core you can use TagWith

```
var result = db.Albums
               .TagWith(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Interesting. Seems there's a nuget package for EF6 as well. I wasn't aware of this feature. Seems I could make an IQueryable extension method that performs the tagging with some sort of identifier that I can parse out of the resulting query in the interceptor. If you flush out your answer with some details so others find it helpful I'll accept this as the answer