# How to know where query is executed in EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-profiler

I get this query in sql profiler

```sql
SELECT [r].[OfficialFactorId], [r].[AllowCalcTax], [r].[AndicatorNumber], [r].[BasketId], [r].[BookDateTime], [r].[CalculatedWithUserCurrency], [r].[CashPayementPercent], [r].[Comment], [r].[CorporationId], [r].[CreateUserId], [r].[CustomerId], [r].[Date], [r].[EnvoyAddress], [r].[EnvoyEmail], [r].[EnvoyFirstName], [r].[EnvoyFullname], [r].[EnvoyLastName], [r].[EnvoyMobile], [r].[EnvoyNationalCode], [r].[EnvoyPhone], [r].[EnvoyTel], [r].[FactorStatusId], [r].[FactorTypeId], [r].[FirstPaymentPercent], [r].[HasRemaine], [r].[Info], [r].[IsDeleted], [r].[IsLock], [r].[IsManually], [r].[Number], [r].[ParentFactorId], [r].[PassengerFillTypeId], [r].[PaymentTypeId], [r].[PreFactor], [r].[PrePaymentPrice], [r].[PrePaymentType], [r].[Recipted], [r].[ReferenceNumber], [r].[RefundCardNumber], [r].[RegisterDateTime], [r].[RequestUserId], [r].[Revoked], [r].[RowVersion], [r].[SaleCorporationFinancialPeriodId], [r].[SaleMethod], [r].[SettlementTypeId], [r].[SiteAddress], [r].[TourDateId], [r].[TrackingResponsibleUserId], [r].[UserAgentHeader], [r].[UserNote], [r].[order_id]
FROM [ORD].[OfficialFactor] AS [r]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [ORD].[OfficialFactorDetail] AS [x]
    WHERE ([x].[IsDeleted] = 0) AND ([r].[OfficialFactorId] = [x].[OfficialFactorId]))
ORDER BY [r].[OfficialFactorId]
```

This query genrated with `EF Core` and this is very slow and return `3,000,000` records.

I want to know where query is executing in project. project is very big and i can't find the query.

In `SQL` profiler only show `UserName` and `Query`.

Is there any way to know where query is  executed?

Comment: Start with the Where clause - look for queries where `IsDeleted` is in the Where clause. Then on to the Order clause - search for `.OrderBy(z => z.OfficialFactorId)` or the like.

Comment: It may be something like `var bob = OfficialFactors.Where(z => z.Detail.Any(y => !y.IsDeleted)).OrderBy(x => x.OfficialFactorId);`

Comment: For EF6, this answer should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62486356/detect-or-pass-calling-method-in-entity-framework-6-and-entity-framework-core-vi/62487505#62487505

Answer (score 2):

A really helpful feature with EF core is the .TagWith method.

An example being:

```
var peopleList = dbContext.people
    .Where(b => b.Name != null)
    .TagWith("Getting peoplelist query.")
    .ToList();
```

which would translate to :

```
-- Getting peoplelist query.

SELECT [b].[PersonId], [b].[Email], [b].[Name], [b].[Title]
      FROM [Person] AS [b]
      WHERE [b].[Name] IS NOT NULL
```

It would help you Track down the query that is causing the issue

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my problem is **i don't know where query is executing**. your solution don't any help to me